# Is there an easy way to make SPA auth in Vue.js + Laravel without using JWT?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building an App in Laravel + Vue.js. I have a bunch of views ready I wanted to make it SPA, looking it up I found out about JWT authentication, but I had a lot of problems implementing it and I find it way too complicated (you have to change too many things to the code, make a lot of promises and stuff I still don't understand).

When you first build an app in Laravel you execute a command in console which creates you a Login/Register/Logout module automatically, is there a way I can implement that with Vue (using the router, axios or whatever) so I don't have to use JWT?

Comment: Please post your codes here.

Comment: What parts of the JWT implementation are you having trouble with? I'd really recommend getting familiar with JWT authentication.

Comment: You can use passport for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, It will mean creating an additional column in your `users` table where you will save user tokens. Although is is not optimal.

Because these tokens are required for performing `GET`, `POST`, `CREATE` and `DELETE` Requests, you will have to append the `token` as a second parameter for all `api` requests.

Below shows a sample `code`

For my `auth`, I have used the defaul auth that `Laravel` ships with which means a user is by default, redirected to `home.blade.php` file, that looks like this

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <App :user='{{ auth()->user() }}'></App>
    <!-- The :user has to be accepted as a prop in the App component -->
@endsection
```

In the App.vue file, which is the layout of your `SPA` you can do somthing like this

```
<template>
   <div> 
       <router-view> </router-view> <!-- for all other components -->
   </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "App",

    props: [
        'user'
    ],

    components:{

    },

    created(){
        window.axios.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                if(config.method === 'get'){
                    config.url = config.url + '?api_token='+ this.user.api_token;
                }else{
                    config.data = {
                    ...config.data,
                    api_token: this.user.api_token
                    }
                }


                return config;
            }
        )
    }

    //to set the api_token globally such that it does not need to be typed in eveywhere, we do it whe the component is created/mounted
    //let me know if it helps


}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

For your logout,

```
<router-link to="/logout"> Logout </router-link>
//in your Logout component, you can have something like this

<template>
    <div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Logout',

    created(){
        axios.post('/logout', {})
        .finally(err => {
            window.location = '/login';
        })
    }
}
</script>
```